# Extracting 25W from a pair of 18650 li-ion in series

Tags: power, lithium-ion, battery-operated

If I have 2 bats of li-ion in series. 8.4V full charged and 6V full discharged. What should be their minimum mAh capacity, if they are 18650 size, and considering a constant load of 25W.

25W/6V = 4.16A?

Would they heat much at that power?

Comment: How long do you want that power for? If half an hour isn't enough, 18650s are out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should be their minimum mAh capacity, if they are 18650 size, and considering a constant load of 25W.

Rather than look for a minimum mAh capacity, look for a cell rated for at least 5A continuous discharge, or ideally higher.  For example, a quick search shows that the LG Chem sells the HG2 series, which are rated for 200 cycles at 20A discharge.  I have no personal experience with that product, so it is worth looking at other high current batteries to see which makes the most sense for your application.

> Would they heat much at that power?

It is going to depend on the battery.  A 20A rated part probably doesn't get too hot at 4A, but cooling might be a good idea if you're going to sustain that load for long.

Comment: 5C discharge rate is something of commom use today, I have contact with some manufacturers

Comment: 1500mAh x 5 = 7.5A, and also can use internal protection circuit clamping at 5A current instantaneous. And it charge at 0.5A average.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested discharge rates are usually 1C - one full discharge per hour. This equates to, for example for a 1500 mAh cell, 1.5 A discharge rate. There are specialized cells that can go much higher C discharge rate - RC car and helicopter cells can be rated 50C or more. There are also lower discharge rate cells that can be rated as longer life, higher temperature ranges, etc.

I haven't seen a 4100mAh 18650 cell, so it's unlikely your cell could handle that rate of discharge safely.

Comment: 3C and 5C are low cost also, discharge rate